# How to get url from s3.getSignedUrl()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to store some images using AWS S3. Everything is running smoothly until I started getting some 400s on PUTting images on URLs I got from s3.getSignedUrl. At that time my code looked like this:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey
});

const imageRouter = express.Router();

imageRouter.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  const type = req.body.ContentType;
  const Key = `${req.session.user.id}/${uuid()}.${type}`;

  s3.getSignedUrl(
    'putObject',
    {
      Bucket: 'cms-bucket-06',
      ContentType: type,
      Key
    },
    (err, url) => {
      console.log('URL ', url); res.send({ Key, url });
    }
  );
});
```

I followed link from error and I found out that "The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.".
So I did. Like that:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
```

But now I get no URL in my callback function. It's undefined. What am I still missing here?

EDIT: 
Alright, I added my key back to the constructor and I'm able to upload images. New problem is that I can't open them. I get access denied every time. I added proper bucket policy but it doesn't help :(

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1547050603038",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1547050601490",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If `url` is undefined then did you check what's in the `err`?. Also `${req.session.user.id}/${uuid()}.${type}`, what is the expected value it is supposed to return?

Comment: Your replacement AWS.S3() constructor only has signatureVersion. Did you mean to remove accessKeyId and secretAccessKey?